# Gerenciar variáveis com sessão PHP

Tags: php, session

Preciso pegar o valor de um input text armazená-lo e utilizá-lo em uma outra página que se abre automaticamente (popup) quando o botão Enviar do form é pressionado.

Ele consegue fazer isso, porém o que está acontecendo é que quando aperto o botão a primeira vez ele não pega, quando aperto para enviar o form uma segunda vez ele envia o valor que estava na primeira e assim por diante... ideias?

Comment: tente colocar `action="NomeDoPopUp"` no seu formulario.

Comment: continua dando o mesmo problema e além disso tem mais uma coisa, a página 1 é um form que faz uma entrada no banco de dados e só após essa entrada é criado um ID (autoincremental) que eu vou usar no popup... logo o action do primeiro form não pode ser o popup... =/

Comment: Vou tentar explicar o caso. 
Página1: faz o cadastro principal gerando automáticamente um código na tabela do banco
Página2 (popup): traz uma lista de checkboxes com opções e que serão atreladas ao código que citei acima em uma outra tabela do banco
Por conta disso eu preciso que o primeiro form seja enviado primeiro e só então  uma outra página venha com os check.
O PopUp é somente questão estética, para não abrir uma página somente para isso... se tiver alguma outra solução estou ouvindo... (lendo haha)

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está errado. Você está definindo o valor da `$_SESSION['nome']` com um `$_POST` que ainda nem existe e a mesma situação se repete ao chamar o popup.

Faça assim

```
<?php

    session_start('professor');

    $chamarPopup = false;

    //Verifica se existe um $_POST chamado nomeP, que é o name do seu input.
    if (isset($_POST['nomeP']) && !empty($_POST['nomeP'])) {
        $_SESSION['nome'] = $_POST['nomeP'];
        $chamarPopup = true;
    }

?>

<form method="post" name="formTest">
    <input type="text" name="nomeP" value="Nome Professor">
    <input type="submit" value="PopUp">
</form>
```

No final da sua página, depois da tag `</body>` coloque isso

```
<?php

    if ($chamarPopup === true) {
        echo "<script>window.onload = function(){";
        echo "varWindow = window.open ('cadastro_prof_disc.php', 'popup', 'width=1024, height=350, top=300, left=400%, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes,')";
        echo "};</script>";
    }

?>
```

No popup não precisa mudar nada.

Só pra constar: eu não recomendo usar popup, pois, a maioria dos navegadores modernos bloqueiam todos por padrão e, usuários menos experientes não sabem como fazer para que eles sejam exibidos.